# x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ doesn't link GLFW on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, compiler-errors, cross-compiling

I'm doing some stuff with OpenGL and I wanted to compile an exe for Windows with x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ but it doesn't link GLFW. When trying to compile it says:

```
main.cpp:4:10: fatal error: GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

I used `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -m64 ~myproject/glad/*.c main.cpp -o test.exe -lglfw -lGL` in terminal.

Compiling with `g++ -m64 ~myproject/glad/*.c main.cpp -o test -lglfw -lGL` has no problems.

Comment: You haven't set `-I` for GLFW parent include directory.

Comment: That's a compilation error, not a link error. It never even gets to the linker stage.

Comment: @273K I tried adding '-I/usr/include' but it printed a wall of errors and warnings in the files which are in the include directory

Comment: @PhoenixWright You need the GLFW library installed for the cross compilation environment. It should come with headers in a separate directory than the system headers in `/usr/include`. You might need to build it yourself or find it packaged for Ubuntu somewhere. I don't think the default repository has that.

Comment: @user17732522 thanks for hint, I might try it later but I'll probably give up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to compile GLFW with MinGW, or find a precompiled version. MinGW can't reuse the Linux version of GLFW you already have installed.

I made a tool called [quasi-msys2](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2) to automatically install libraries for MinGW, from [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/)'s vast repositories of prebuilt libraries.

Install dependencies: (this assumes Ubuntu 22.04, adjust for your Linux distribution)

```bash
sudo apt install make wget tar zstd gpg wine # Wine is optional but recommended.
# Install Clang and LLD (recommended)
bash -c "$(wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh)"
```

Install quasi-msys2:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/holyblackcat/quasi-msys2
cd quasi-msys2
make install _gcc _gdb _glfw
# We install GCC only for the libraries it provides, we'll be compiling with Clang instead.
```

Open its shell:

```bash
env/shell.sh
```

Compile:

```bash
win-clang++ 1.cpp -o program.exe `pkg-config --libs --cflags glfw3`
```

Quasi-msys2 doesn't need an external MinGW installation, only Clang (a regular native version) to cross-compile with. Though it might be possible to use an external MinGW GCC with libraries downloaded from it.

Comment: When trying to run win-clang++ it says '~/quasi-msys2/env/wrappers/win-clang++: 2: : Permission denied'

Comment: @PhoenixWright Can you paste the entire log to pastebin?

Comment: where do I copy log from?

Comment: @PhoenixWright I mean just from the terminal itself.

Comment: 'john@john-Default-string UCRT64 ~/stuff/opengl
$ win-clang++ ./glad/*.c main.cpp -o test.exe `pkg-config --libs --cflags glfw3`
/home/john/quasi-msys2/env/wrappers/win-clang++: 2: : Permission denied
' that's all

Comment: @PhoenixWright I mean from all preceding commands too.

Comment: 'john@john-Default-string:~/quasi-msys2$ env/shell.sh
--- binfmt.mk
`binfmt_misc` mounted? YES
`binfmt_misc` enabled? YES
Executable format registered? YES
Executable format enabled? YES
--- fakebin.mk
Nothing to do.

--- vars.src
[WARNING] Didn't find symlink `/ucrt64` -> `/home/john/quasi-msys2/root/ucrt64`.
It can improve compatibility in some cases. Consider creating it using following command:
    sudo ln -nfs "/home/john/quasi-msys2/root/ucrt64" /ucrt64

MSYSTEM_PREFIX = /home/john/quasi-msys2/root/ucrt64'

first part since Ive no reputation to enter chat and there's more

Comment: 'Guessing a compiler... To override, set `MINGW_CC` and `MINGW_CXX` and restart.
Trying native Clang + LLD...
  Guessed Clang version suffix: WIN_CLANG_VER = NONE
  You can override it by setting it to a number or to `NONE` for no suffix.
Fail.
Trying MSYS2 Clang... (not recommended)
Fail.
Trying MSYS2 GCC...
Success.
CC  = gcc
CXX = g++'
then I tried win-clang++
'john@john-Default-string:~/quasi-msys2$ make install _gcc _gdb _glfw
Makefile:937: *** Following packages are already requested: mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-gdb mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-glfw' if need

Comment: @PhoenixWright This means you didn't install Clang. That's the second command in my answer, starting from `bash -c ...`. In the future, I suggest using https://pastebin.com/ for long logs.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QMK5SJrp

Comment: @PhoenixWright Hmm, ok, you have two options. Long-term it's better to figure out why Clang isn't installing (maybe you'll find some instructions [here](https://apt.llvm.org/)). But for now, you can just compile with `g++` instead (after running `env/shell.sh` in that shell it will point to MinGW GCC). It will be slower, as it runs in Wine.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/csu7vxam And anyway thank you for trying to help me

Comment: @PhoenixWright Hmm. Then you need Clang. GCC in Wine is wonky.

Comment: @PhoenixWright Did you figure it out?

Comment: I downloaded packages and your quasi-msys2 worked. Thank you very much!!

Comment: I mean, it produced exe but https://pastebin.com/uEw9dYHk

Comment: @PhoenixWright Do you have some weird characters in the username? Maybe that causes issues; you can try moving quasi-msys2 to a path without those (or adding a symlink as `env/shell.sh` suggests when you launch it; perhaps it will work too).

Comment: wine works only from quasi-msys2 's environment, is that ok?

Comment: @PhoenixWright Yes, that's normal. That's just because your program relies on some `.dll`s in `quasi-msys2/root/ucrt64/bin`, which `env/shell.sh` adds to `WINEPATH`. The same issue occurs on Windows with regular MSYS2, where the DLLs must be present in `PATH`. To make your app run from anywhere (and on Windows machines), you need to distribute those DLLs with your .exe, run `win-ldd program.exe` (but first `make install _ntldd`) to get a list of DLLs you need to copy (ignore everything not in that `.../bin` directory).

Comment: Do I just place them in same folder with exe or can I include them into exe or should I make an installer?

Comment: @PhoenixWright Same folder is ok. Imbedding into .exe is called "static linking" (`win-clang++ 1.cpp -o program.exe --static \`pkg-config --libs --cflags --static glfw3\``), but it has some issues (users can't update/change the libraries; and some libraries have [licenses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License) that force you to make the app opensource if you link statically). Making an installer doesn't accomplish anything other than looking professional.